# Sending an Email from Python via Office 365 Corporate Account

Tags: python, outlook, office365, email

I am trying to send an email via Python from my Office 365 corporate account to another Office 365 corporate account. The objective is to send an email once the script runs successfully.

I've checked the email ID and password, however, can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

```
    import smtplib
    message = "Execution Successful"
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.login('userid@corporateemail.com', 'password')
    mailserver.sendmail('userid@corporateemail.com', 'userid@corporateemail.com', message)
    mailserver.quit()
```

This should trigger an email to the user. However, it gives an error message.
Here is the output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-45-663ff7ed4e61>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/qy115/Desktop/Updated Python/Test/EmailTest.py', wdir='C:/Users/qy115/Desktop/Updated Python/Test')

  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/qy115/Desktop/Updated Python/Test/EmailTest.py", line 20, in <module>
    mailserver.starttls()

  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 752, in starttls
    (resp, reply) = self.docmd("STARTTLS")

  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 420, in docmd
    return self.getreply()

  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\smtplib.py", line 390, in getreply
    + str(e))

  SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: what's the error type?

Comment: The traceback seems incomplete.

Comment: @HenryYik My apologies, I have edited the question to add the missing error message.

Comment: In case you can't solve your problem, check out win32com.client. I do what you describe with that flawlessly.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've added the missing portion. Apologies for missing it out earlier.

Comment: @FatihAkici I did and win32com.client worked for me too. However, all emails were getting sent from my email address.
The script would be put on a server and run via cron jobs. I am not sure if win32com.client would work then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same thing. I don't think you can use username and password to authenticate anymore with Office 365. You have to follow these instructions which from what I understand requires you to connect to the Office 365 via a secure app in Microsoft Azure service:

https://pypi.org/project/O365/#different-authentication-interfaces

I have managed to authenticate, however, not able to retrieve the required token to get into my account and send an email. Maybe you will have better success? If anyone has done this successfully, please let us know as I can't work it out.

Answer (score -2):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
mail_content = "Hello, This is a simple mail. There is only text, no 
attachments are there The mail is sent using Python SMTP library"
#The mail addresses and password
sender_address = 'userid@corporateemail.com'
sender_pass = 'XXXXXXXXX'
receiver_address = 'userid@corporateemail.com'
#Setup the MIME
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python. It has an attachment.'   
#The subject line
#The body and the attachments for the mail
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
#Create SMTP session for sending the mail
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #use gmail with port
session.starttls() #enable security
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```